# Form submit() not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, post, form-submit, array-multisort

I have a php isset if statement and a javascript for submit that just doesn't seem to want to submit correctly. I have tried:

```
document.getElementByID("form1").submit();
document.form1.submit();
document.forms[form1].submit();
```

and tried all these variations with and without a variable declaration using this.value.

The code below has the javascript, and it 'seems' to be submitting (the page refreshes and the 'select' option defaults back to the option 0, but it seems that no form data has been submitted, and the array is not correctly sorted. I'm very new to php and js (just started this week) so I apologise in advance :)

The document also has `<html>` and `<head>` tag, and `obstart()` and a `sessionstart()` tag if it helps.

```
<script>
function submitform() 
  {
  document.getElementByID("form1").submit();
  }
</script>
```

```html
# array_multisort

$sort = array();
foreach($columbs as $k=>$v) 
{
  $sort['2'][$k] = $v['2'];
  $sort['1'][$k] = $v['1'];
  $sort['4'][$k] = $v['4'];
  $sort['3'][$k] = $v['3'];
  $sort['5'][$k] = $v['5'];
  $sort['6'][$k] = $v['6'];
  $sort['7'][$k] = $v['7'];
  $sort['8'][$k] = $v['8'];
}

# sort by event_type desc and then title asc

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
$sortbysubmit = $_POST['myselect'];
switch($sortbysubmit)
  {
  case "0": $sortby0 = array_multisort($sort['0'], SORT_ASC, $columbs); break;
  case "B1": $sortby1 = array_multisort($sort['1'], SORT_ASC, $columbs); break;
  case "B2": $sortby2 = array_multisort($sort['2'], SORT_ASC, $columbs); break;
  default: $sortby0 = array_multisort($sort['0'], SORT_ASC, $columbs); break;
  echo 'hello';
  break;
  }
}
else
  {
  array_multisort($sort['0'], SORT_ASC, $columbs);
  }
  ?>

<!--form1-->        

<form method="post" action="" id="form1" name="form1">
  <label for="form1">1</label><br>
  <select name="myselect" 2="myselect" onchange="submitform()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="B1">1</option>
    <option value="B2">2</option>
  </select>
  <noscript>
    <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
  </noscript>
</form>
```

Comment: You doesnt seem to have name attribute to submit button, and therefore $_POST['formSubmit'] is not set. You can try checking for only $_POST. that is if(!empty($_POST)){

Comment: I tried your solution and it almost works. Value 0 doesn't seem to sort however the other 2 values do.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking the formSubmit key in your post, but you are never sendig it. Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form1" name="form1">
  <label for="form1">1</label><br>
  <select name="myselect" 2="myselect" onchange="submitform()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="B1">1</option>
    <option value="B2">2</option>
  </select>
  <noscript>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Click me" />
  </noscript>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten I'd taken that out some time ago because it didn't seem to work for me. I'm using wamp btw.

Comment: Also, the ' 2="myselect" ' is actually ' id="myselect" ' in my real code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
if(!empty($_POST)):

//your submission process code goes here

endif;
```

You doesn't seem to have name attribute to submit button, and therefore $_POST['formSubmit'] is not set.

Comment: Almost works :)! It sorts for values B1 and B2 but when I click value 0 it doesn't sort back to default.

Answer (score 0):

I found that just by adding

```
if(empty($_POST)):

$sortbysubmit = $_POST['mySelect'];

switch($sortbysubmit)
{
case "SELECT": $sortbyID = array_multisort($sort['ID'], SORT_ASC, $columbs);     break;
}

endif;
```

as well as including vikram's

```
if(!empty($_POST)):

//your submission process code goes here

endif;
```

seems to work. It now sucessfully posts the variable 0 along with 1 and 2. Thanks people :)